# How can I print something only at the first iteration in a for loop?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program where, if the users input is something, then a `for` loop will run that will increase `x`'s value every 3 seconds to 100. I want to print `x`'s value every time it changes. Is this possible to do in the loop?

For example, it will say `game is loading: 1%`, etc. `x` changes every 3 seconds. Is there some way I could delete that string `"game is loading:"` every time the loop iterates every 3 seconds, or is there a simpler way to do it?

I can't use anything outside the loop, since `x` is only initialized inside the loop. I think printing `game is loading` on the first iteration would solve it. Is there a way I could do that, and if so would it solve it?

```
int main()
{
    Menu();
    string input;
    string game("game is loading: ");
    int num = 0;
    cout <<"         : ";
    cin >> input;
    if(input == "yes")
    {
        for(int  x = 0; x<100; x++ )
        {  
            cout << game << x << "%";   
            sleep(3);
        }
    }
    else if(input == "exit"){
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this is: `Game is loading 1%`, `game is loading 2%`, and so on until 100, but I need it to only print that string once;

I tried to use some some other `for` loop inside that one, for example:

```
    //num is 0

    for(int  x = 0; x<100; x++ )
    {
        for(num < 1; num++)
        { 
            cout << game << x << "%";
        }   
        sleep(3);
    }
```

This should only print `game` once, because then `num` would be too large for the parameters. But it doesn't.

Comment: Use a `bool` variable to distinguish 1st from all other iterations maybe?

Comment: Output `game` *outside* the loop? Then used fixed-width output of the numbers, and a few backspaces (it only moves the cursor) to go back to the beginning of the number? Or print the whole thing, with `game`, and use a carriage-return to go back to the beginning of the line and overwrite it the next iteration.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think he is looking for a way to delete a printed line and replace it with something else on the terminal screen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how would i do that i dont quiet understand what you mean how can use it to distinguish the first iteration

Comment: Are you asking how to print one (or two) `^H` to erase previous character(s)? You may want to use a library for this in the long run. For a Great Joy also do a spinning cursor.

Comment: I assume this is some kind of technology test where you're adding a sleep instead of an actually-required time-consuming operation purely for testing purposes. But if you're sleeping just to make it appear like your game is complex enough to require a pre-load, but isn't, then I dunno what to say.

Comment: @iDontLikeJavascript _"How would I do that ..."_ Set it `true` before entering a loop, handle the `true` state inside the loop, and Set it to `false` after you did so. That simple.

Comment: @iDontLikeJavascript Even if you accomplish waiting in the loop, I don't think the output is what you will expect.  C++ has no standard way of moving the cursor around on the terminal.  As mentioned, you need to use a library, or if you are using Windows, the Console API.

Comment: "*I think he is looking for a way to delete a printed line and replace it with something else on the terminal screen*" - standard C++ I/O can't do that.  You need to use platform-specific terminal APIs, or a 3rd party library like ncurses.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you i think ill use a carriage return i wasnt aware of that escape sequence.

Comment: The best way to edit text in C++'s IO Streams is to get it right the first time and not have to go back to fix things. IO Streams are a brutally simple interface because they have to support systems with a simple serial port and a CPU with the computational power of a Dorito the same as they support a PC with a Desktop GUI and a full-featured terminal program. The terminal program gets the short end of the stick.

Comment: @paddy basicly.

Comment: Hint: `ncurses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way I could delete that string `"game is loading:"` every time the loop iterates every 3 seconds

Standard C++ I/O cannot do that.  To accomplish that, you will have to use platform-specific terminal APIs directly, or a 3rd party wrapper library such as ncurses.

Comment: Backspaces work pretty often (if wonky and unpleasant), though.

Comment: That is terminal-specific behavior.

Comment: Yep, and works pretty often.

Comment: The question was not about a portable solution. Obviously the author of the question in in their first week of c++ and he wants to make it work *somehow*. As such, this is not a real answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

On *many* terminals, you can get away with simply writing backspace characters, then overwriting that text. It's no guarantee, but it is probably the simplest approach you could take that might suit your purposes without needing to use a library.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Loading: " << std::flush;

    int percent_complete = 0;
    int rewind_chars = 0;
    
    do {
        // Simulate processing load
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

        // Update percentage completion
        percent_complete++;
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << percent_complete << '%';
        auto text = oss.str();

        // Overwrite previous percentage output
        std::cout << std::string(rewind_chars, '\b') << text << std::flush;
        rewind_chars = text.size();
    } while (percent_complete != 100);

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly
AND
if you do not care about portability
AND
if you do not want to deep dive into platform specific terminal control libraries, then the following code might give you pointers for a very primitive and basic approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << "-------Game loading------";
  std::flush(std::cout);
  sleep(3);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";
    std::flush(std::cout);
    std::cout << "            " << i << "%" << "           ";
    std::flush(std::cout);
    sleep(3);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note this may or may not be respected depending on the terminal

Comment: @user4581301 Yes - this is one of my IF clauses on top.

Comment: @BitTickler my terminal gives me a random string of numbers then ends the program it seems like the for loop doesnt get run or somthing

Comment: @iDontLikeJavascript Then you are on a terminal, where this trick is not working. Sorry - in those cases you need to read up on the specifics of your terminal and consider using libraries like ncurses or termio or however they are called. Especially if you use a terminal to a remote server, you might be out of luck and need a bit more fiddling.